# Beta integral and Chu-Vandermonde identity

Tags: sequences-and-series, special-functions

Chu vandermonde identity states that     ${s+t \choose n}=\sum_{k=0}^n {s \choose k}{t \choose n-k} $

Now how to prove that this identity is a discrete form of beta integral?

i see as a starting point to rewrite this identity for n+1 by replacing n by n+1  , then what?  any help? since after writing that i seem to be getting a very crude expression that leads me no where.

Comment: Did you try rewriting the identity using beta functions?

Comment: for writing that i need to know the beta form of chu inequality here which i dont have, any further help ?

Comment: This might be useful: $Beta(1+k, 1+n-k) = \frac{1}{n+1} \frac{1}{\binom{n}{k}}$

Comment: Do you want to find $p,q$ such that $\dbinom{s+t}{n}$ is expressed in terms of $B(p,q)$?